# Expo dev build React Native Cannot GET /index.bundle

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, build, expo

I am getting the following error when trying a development build for iOS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /index.bundle</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

I am fairly new to React Native and brand new to development builds on Expo, but I am trying to connect my iOS client on my iPhone to my Node server running on AWS. I got the above error on the Expo app that was installed on my iPhone and the below error on the terminal running the server:

```
GET / 304 5.223 ms - -
GET / 200 0.993 ms - 5
HEAD / 200 0.405 ms - 5
GET /message?role=ios 404 2.159 ms - 146
GET /index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false 404 0.485 ms - 151
GET /inspector/device?name=iPhone&app=bundleid 404 0.314 ms - 155
GET /message?role=ios 404 0.363 ms - 146
GET /inspector/device?name=iPhone&app=bundleid 404 0.296 ms - 155
GET /inspector/device?name=iPhone&app=bundleid 404 0.645 ms - 155
GET /message?role=ios 404 0.500 ms - 146
```

Am I missing some code or files that I should have in my server or client for development builds? I can't find anything on what index.bundle is either, so if someone can explain that as well, that would be very helpful.